# How can I test binding of JSX form input field with JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

following is the code that needs to be tested.

```js
class Booking extends Component{
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          formValue: {       
            customerName: ""
          }
       }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(event) {
          const target = event.target;
          const value = target.value;
          const name = target.name;
          const { formValue } = this.state;
          this.setState({
                formValue: { ...formValue, [name]: value }
           });
      }
      
      render(){
          return {
              <form>
                  <input name="customerName" value={this.state.formValue.customerName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              </form>      
          }
       }
    }
```

I want to write a test case that checks whenever i enter value in the input field the same should be assigned to `customerName` of `formValue`. if not the test case should fail.

Comment: it seems like you are missing change handlers in your code for exact functionality you want to test

Comment: updated the code with change handler..

Comment: How did you try test it? Can you show the test code?